# Best way to downcast to right template from abstract class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I recently had a C++ assignment, where I was confronted to a problem about polymorphism.

We needed to store values in a templated class, which was inheriting from an abstract interface class.

```
enum eOperandType {
    Int8,
    Int16,
    Int32,
    Float,
    Double
};

class IOperand {
public:
    virtual eOperandType getType() const = 0; // Type of the instance
    virtual IOperand const *operator+(IOperand const &rhs) const = 0;
    virtual ~IOperand() {}
};

template<typename T>
class Operand : public IOperand {
public:
    Operand(T const &n, eOperandType type);    
    eOperandType getType() const;    
    IOperand const *operator+(IOperand const &rhs) const;

    T const value;
    eOperandType const type;
};
```

For all the assignment, we were forbidden to edit the IOperand class, but free to use any class we need behind.

Later on the code execution, numbers are instanced and then stored in a container as IOperand*. We then get this list in order to manipulate numbers.

My problem was to find how to downcast the IOperand* into the right Operand type, in order to manipulate it and get it's value.

I tried multiples approaches for a week, looking into all templates behaviour (with hitting a wall when I tried to use `Operand<op.getType()>` with T being the enum)

My actual design is using a lot of switches:

```
switch (op.value->getType()) {
    case Int8:
        if (dynamic_cast<Operand<int8_t>*>(op.value.get())->value != dynamic_cast<Operand<int8_t>*>(stack.front().get())->value) {
            throw RuntimeError("Assert failed. Whoopsie");
        }
        break;
    case Int16:
        if (dynamic_cast<Operand<int16_t>*>(op.value.get())->value != dynamic_cast<Operand<int16_t>*>(stack.front().get())->value) {
            throw RuntimeError("Assert failed. Whoopsie");
        }
        break;
    case Int32:
        if (dynamic_cast<Operand<int32_t>*>(op.value.get())->value != dynamic_cast<Operand<int32_t>*>(stack.front().get())->value) {
            throw RuntimeError("Assert failed. Whoopsie");
        }
        break;
    case Float:
        if (dynamic_cast<Operand<float>*>(op.value.get())->value != dynamic_cast<Operand<float>*>(stack.front().get())->value) {
            throw RuntimeError("Assert failed. Whoopsie");
        }
        break;
    case Double:
        if (dynamic_cast<Operand<double>*>(op.value.get())->value != dynamic_cast<Operand<double>*>(stack.front().get())->value) {
            throw RuntimeError("Assert failed. Whoopsie");
        }
        break;
    default:
        throw RuntimeError("wut");
        break;
}
```

What would be the best clean solution to solve my problem? I need to "downcast" my value at multiples places and functions in order to manipulate the value, the assert code here is just an example among many others.

I can here use C++14, but not any external libs.

Comment: The idea of an interface is to expose most of the operations that you need to perform on a particular type. If you find yourself downcasting often, that's the sign of a bad design. I don't see anything wrong with the big switch statement.

Comment: The very design of that interface's `operator +` is suspect. I realize you can't change it, but it in itself is fundamentally whack. A lhs-const-ref + rhs-const-ref results in a const *pointer* ??. What fiend came up with that?

Comment: @WhozCraig Just checked the subject, and the interface is right. I may have removed the spaces after the * and &. `virtual IOperand const * operator+( IOperand const & rhs ) const = 0;` is what I just copied and pasted from the subject.

Comment: @Cubox I had little doubt it was correctly posted, which was why I questioned the sanity of the person who contrived it. When I first saw the question I wondered whether the assignment was trying to drive you toward covariant return types, but that isn't a silver bullet here.

Comment: not the answer, but an interface like this: https://github.com/JasonL9000/cppcon14 would make your code probably look a bit nicer

Answer (score 0):

> hitting a wall when I tried to use Operand with T being
>   the enum

Templates are evaluated at compile time. The compiler generates code for each type you have used. A dynamic value like `op.getType()` would require the compiler to *create code after you have compiled*, which is certainly possible in JIT compiled languages, but not in C++.

I'm afraid there is no 'pretty' solution to your problem. You really need a kind of switch statement as you've shown, and decide your cast based on the value of `getType()`. Depending on your use cases, virtual functions could help you, e.g. if you would like to know the byte size of `T`

```
virtual size_t getSizeOf()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}
```

but since you're not allowed to modify `IOperand`, you're stuck with your solution.